# switch case: several equivalent cases expressions in r

Tags: r, switch-statement, expression, case

In r-programming:
i want to use the same method to handle cases 1 and 10, ie, when the loop is in round 1 and then in 10 again. same for 2 and 11.
is there a way to have several case expressions being handled by the same method
for k == 1 and later also fo 10 it should use the first case and for k ==2 and later 11 it should use the second case. the above code doesn't work.

```
for(i in 1:x) {      

    switch(k,
             "1", "10"= { 
            correct <- test[21,1]
            current <- test[i-p,1]
            if(all(correct == current)){     
              answers[i-p,k] <- c(1)
            } else{
              answers[i-p,k] <- c(0)
            }
          },
      "2","11" ={
        correct <- test[21,2]
        current <- test[i,2]
        if(all(correct == current)){     
          answers[i,k] <- c(1)
        } else{
          answers[i,k] <- c(0)
        }
       }
}
```

the same code for only one case expression works:

```
for(i in 1:x) {      

    switch(k,
             "1" = { 
            correct <- test[21,1]
            current <- test[i-p,1]
            if(all(correct == current)){     
              answers[i-p,k] <- c(1)
            } else{
              answers[i-p,k] <- c(0)
            }
          },
      "2" ={
        correct <- test[21,2]
        current <- test[i,2]
        if(all(correct == current)){     
          answers[i,k] <- c(1)
        } else{
          answers[i,k] <- c(0)
        }
       }
}
```

in java we can use case 1 : case 2 to do that. how is it done in r?
i appreciate your help. alternatively i could also copy the code but don't want to if i can avoid it.

Comment: You could use several `if()` statements, where the test would be something along the lines of `if (any(case %in% c("1", "10")))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal choice would be to remap your `k` to the overlapping cases.  Example:

```
k<-1:20
kmatch<-(k-1)%%9 +1
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
```

Then feed `kmatch` to your `case` expression

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is along the lines of

```
f = function(x)
    switch(x, "1"=, "10"="first", "11"="eleventh", "none")
```

Note the equal sign after each named expression, other than the default value.

```
> f("1")
[1] "first"
> f("10")
[1] "first"
> f("11")
[1] "eleventh"
> f("12")
[1] "none"
```

This is documented in the third paragraph of the 'Details' section of `?switch`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the OP's question, which was how to collapse the number of cases.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it's consistent with 'In java we can...' and the behavior of `switch` constructs in other programming languages, and with the non-functional code of their first code chunk.

Comment: Maybe so, but it's not the point. In addition, we probably should warn the OP that he's lucky that `R` coerces numerics to their comparable characters when doing things like  `1 == "1"`